# How do I check a field name from a Django form in html?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form that contains several fields I am looping through.  I want to branch the code if the field is the "comment" field, something like this:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field == form.fields.comment %}
        <do something>
    {% else %}
        <do something else>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What is the correct syntax for the 2nd line?  The current line always fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it would be:

```
{% if field.field == form.fields.comment %}
```